# MAUI: Any alternative packages for Xam.Plugin.Media, DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView, Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker

Tags: maui

I am using below packages in my `Xamarin Forms` project:

**Xam.Plugin.Media**: For opening camera and gallery in device and pick pictures

**DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView**: For showing multiple items on a row

**Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker**: For picking files from the device

Now I am migrating my `Xamarin Forms` project to `MAUI` and I research for the alternative package for the above mentioned packages. So far I didn't get anything useful.

Is there any alternative packages?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?tabs=android

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android

Comment: @DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView Any alternative for `DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that might help you could be "CollectionView" from maui controls, A  simple example of a view with 2 (or many spans as you want) could be:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Status}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

After that you will get multiple binded view objects in the same row with your data as you said

For more info you can read: [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/)

Use [Media picker for photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?tabs=android) for picking picture from gallery or open camera.

Use [File picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android) for picking a file from device.

Comment: It is working as I expected, but not able to scroll to bottom of collection view. My collectionview is inside of a stacklayout, I changed it to grid, but still not scrollable.

Comment: After setting CollectionView.HeightRequest, the scroll feature is working fine.